# Importar dados do MS Access para Sql Server via código

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, microsoft-access, tsql

Preciso importar dados que estão em um banco Access via código para Sql Server.
Meu software que é feito em C# por muitos anos foi integrado a uma base de dados Access. A partir de agora estamos migrando para Sql Server e a intenção é que na atualização para a próxima versão o sistema passe a funcionar apenas com o Sql Server. Penso a princípio em criar um banco Sql com os mesmos nomes de tabelas e colunas e pelo software fazer a leitura das tabelas Access e salvar os dados no banco Sql. Existe algum outro meio mais prático para fazer isso via **código**?

Estive pesquisando e achei apenas ferramentas prontas, mas nada via programação.

Comment: Sua intenção é de realmente fazer apenas via código?

Comment: Isso! Pois já existe uma base de usuários usando o software antigo com o banco Access. A intenção é que na atualização para a próxima versão o sistema passe a funcionar apenas com o Sql Server e não temos como acessar máquina por máquina para migrar de banco de dados.

Comment: Você pode utilizar o Access como front-end para SQL Server; vide tabela vinculada. Ou, em programação T-SQL, você pode abrir as tabelas do Access diretamente no SQL Server. Há várias opções, via código.

Comment: @JoséDiz, Nesse caso não teria que acessar máquina por máquina de cada usuário e instalar o SqlServer para fazer a migração? A intenção é que pelo software, no form criado pelo visual studio, ao fazer a atualização do software para a nova versão, o usuário mesmo possa fazer a migração para o novo banco de dados apenas clicando em um botão Ok, por exemplo.

Answer (score 0):

O que eu faria, imaginando que a sua aplicação é local:
Criaria uma stored procedure de sincronização no Banco SQL e um LinkedServer para o banco Access.

Nessa Stored Procedure faria a sincronização das tabelas pegando do seu access e jogando para dentro do SQL, e essa procedure seria chamada através da sua aplicação C#.

Exemplo de criação de LinkedServer para Access no SQL Server.

```
exec sp_addlinkedserver @server='Access',
@srvproduct='Access',
@provider='Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0',
@datasrc='c:\test.mdb'
```